# Blocos estáticos, herança e construtores em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor, static

Olá, durante meus estudos em Java me deparei com a seguinte dúvida

Dado o código abaixo:

```
   class Foo extends Goo {


    static {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("3");
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("4");
       Foo f = new Foo();

   }

}

class Goo {

    static {
        System.out.println("5");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("6");
    }

    Goo() {
        System.out.println("7");
    }

}
```

Eu obtenho a seguinte saída:

```
5
1
4
6
7
2
3
```

A saída nos leva a inferir a seguinte ordem de execução: blocos estáticos e blocos não-estáticos logo antes dos construtures.  [Essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java)  esclareceu muita coisa pra mim sobre os blocos estáticos. O que não está claro é a ordem em que as classes são carregadas pelo classloader, eu achava que a classe `Foo` seria carregada antes porque está declarada antes, mas a saída me diz que não é assim que funciona. Alguém sabe qual é a regra seguida pelo classloader?

Comment: Não sei responder sobre a regra exata, mas se a classe `Foo` herda de `Goo` é necessário que `Goo` esteja carregada antes que `Foo` possa "se carregar" - por isso a ordem observada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [especificação da linguagem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) dá uma dica. Vamos analisar passo por passo.

Na **carga das classes** o bloco de inicialização estática é chamado.

Primeiro, chama `Goo` (imprime "5") que é necessário para uso em `Foo` (não dá para executar algo antes de sua dependência)

Depois o bloco de `Foo` é executado (imprime "1").

Executa o `main()` (imprime o "4") e instancia uma variável do tipo `Foo`.

Executa a inicialização da instância de `Goo` primeiro (imprime "6" e "7") para uso posterior em `Foo`, já que sem `Goo` existir antes `Foo` não pode existir. Executa tanto o bloco de inicialização de instância quanto o construtor.

`Foo` então é instanciada (imprime "2" e "3").

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a documentação da [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4). No capítulo 12 diz:

> Antes de uma Classe ser inicializada, a sua Superclasse direta deve ser inicializada, mas as Interfaces implementadas pela Classe não são inicializadas. Da mesma forma, as Superinterfaces de uma Interface não são inicializadas antes que a interface ser inicializada.

**Original:**

> Before a class is initialized, its direct superclass must be initialized, but interfaces implemented by the class are not initialized. Similarly, the superinterfaces of an interface are not initialized before the interface is initialized.

### Conceito de Inicialização

Inicialização de uma Classe consiste em executar seus inicializadores estáticos e os inicializadores para campos estáticos (variáveis de classe) declarados na classe.

Inicialização de uma interface consiste em executar os inicializadores para campos (constantes) declarado na interface.