# Ordem da inicialização/instanciamento de classes

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, inicialização

```
class Bird {
 { System.out.print("b1 "); }
 public Bird() { System.out.print("b2 "); }
}
class Raptor extends Bird {
 static { System.out.print("r1 "); }
 public Raptor() { System.out.print("r2 "); }
 { System.out.print("r3 "); }
 static { System.out.print("r4 "); }
}
class Hawk extends Raptor {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.print("pre ");
 new Hawk();
 System.out.println("hawk ");
 }
}
```

O resultado exibido em tela da execução do código acima é:

```
r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk
```

Entretanto estou com dúvida nisso. Entendo que como a classe Hawk precisa da classe Raptor, mas a classe Raptor precisa da classe Bird, então achava que b1 deveria ser o primeiro a ser exibido. Seria possível me explicar passo a passo como acontece as inicializações e justificar o porquê?

Comment: Primeiros são executados os membros estáticos(por isso r1, r4 e pre foram os primeiros), depois seguem a ordem da herança, como você bem observou.

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104512/101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em java, a ordem de inicialização é a seguinte:

> *1- Executa todos os componentes estáticos na ordem em que eles
>   aparecem assim que a classe é carregada na JVM*
>
> *2- Executa todos os componentes de instância na ordem em que eles
>   aparecem na classe, assim que um objeto desta classe é instanciado*
>
> *3- Executa o construtor.*

Portanto, primeiro serão executados os membros com a palavra reservada `static`, no caso da classe informada, foram as chamadas `static { System.out.print("r1 "); }`,  `static { System.out.print("r4 "); }` e o próprio `main`, que também é estático.

Depois, foram executados os membros de instância das classes, pela ordem em que aparecem, no caso do código apresentado, apenas a chamada `{ System.out.print("b1 "); }`.

Agora é que começa a se chamar os construtores, porém, existe herança entre as classes, o que faz a que estiver "mais alta"(no caso a Classe `Bird`) ser a primeira a ter seu construtor, pois a primeira coisa que uma subclasse faz é chamar o construtor da sua superclasse, então primeiro será executado o construtor de `Bird`, depois de `Raptor`, para finalmente o construtor da classe `Hawk` ser executado, e somente após isso a chamada `System.out.println("hawk ");` foi exibida.

Para entender melhor, fiz este exemplo:

```
public class TesteClasse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Filha();
    }
}

class Pai{

    static {System.out.println("Sou um membro estático da classe pai");}

    public Pai(){System.out.println("Sou o construtor da classe pai.");}

        {System.out.println("Sou um membro de estância da classe pai");}
}

class Filha extends Pai{

    {System.out.println("Sou um membro de estância da classe filha");}

    public Filha(){System.out.println("Sou  construtor da classe filha");}

static{System.out.println("Sou um membro estático da classe filha");} 

}
```

A saída é:

```
Sou o método main
Sou um membro estático da classe pai
Sou um membro estático da classe filha
Sou um membro de estância da classe pai
Sou o construtor da classe pai.
Sou um membro de estância da classe filha
Sou  construtor da classe filha
Sou o método main de novo
```

Veja executando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/2SsWKx).

**Referências:**

http://high5devs.com/2014/12/como-funcionam-os-inicializadores-em-java/

http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/10/heranca-de-construtores-e-override.html

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/

Comment: O que é ordem em que eles aparecem?

Comment: @bigown em relação aos membros estáticos, a ordem em que aparecem quando a classe é carregada na JVM, e em relação aos membros de instância, são carregados na ordem em que foram ordenados na classe a qual teve um objeto instanciado. Ficou confuso demais como está na resposta?

Comment: Só tinha faltado isto. "apararecem" é meio genérico.

Comment: @bigown veja se ficou mais objetivo agora.

Comment: Um pouco mas nem tanto, esse "aparece" parece mágico. Eu consigo entender, não sei se todos entendem que significa o que é isso. A execução do seu código parece até mostrar que não é o que você descreveu no amarelinho. Depois até explica melhor.