# Bloco de Inicialização

Tags: java

Estou estudando para certificação.

O [livro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R04DF3I) diz que a ordem de declaração dos atributos e blocos de inicialização deve ser considerada.

---

**Cenário #1:** ao fazer isso:

```
public class Teste {

    {
        System.out.println("Bloco: " + val);
    }

    private int val = 1;

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Val: " + new Teste().getVal());
    }
}
```

O programa não compila e apresenta o erro: `illegal forward reference`.

**Cenário #2:** ao fazer isso:

```
public class Teste {

    {
        val = 2;
    }

    private int val = 1;

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Val: " + new Teste().getVal());
    }
}
```

O programa compila e ao rodar imprime `Val: 1`.

---

Por que não posso referenciar a variável `val` mas posso atribuir um valor a ela?

Além disso, se consegui atribuir esse valor, por que o valor impresso é diferente do atribuído?

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118779/28595

Comment: @Articuno editei a pergunta para deixar um pouco mais focado na dúvida em si.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por que não posso referenciar a variável val mas posso atribuir um valor a ela?

Resumindo: antes de sua declaração pode atribuir um valor à variável, mas não usa-la.

O uso antes da declaração é descrito na especificação do Java [JLS 8.3.2 - Field initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2-300-A):

> *The initializer may use the simple name of any class variable declared in
>
> or inherited by the class, even one whose declaration occurs textually after
> the initializer.*

O ponto seguinte da especificação diz quando não se pode usar uma variável de instância antes da declaração [JLS 8.3.3 - Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3-200):

> *... Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the following are true:*
>
> - *The declaration of an instance variable in a class or interface C appears
>   textually after a use of the instance variable;*
> - *The use is a simple name in either an instance variable initializer of C or
>   an instance initializer of C;*
> - *The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;*
> - *C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.*

Meio complicado mas no fundo diz que o uso da variável tem que ser do lado esquerdo do igual...

> Além disso, se consegui atribuir esse valor, por que o valor impresso é diferente do atribuído?

A inicialização da instância ocorre na mesma ordem do código fonte (esquerda para direita, de cima para baixo). Aqui novamente a especificação [JLS 12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5-220-D)

> *4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers
> for this class, ..., in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually
> in the source code for the class.*

(pontos 1-3 chamada do construtor da classe pai (super), ponto 5 construtor da atual classe)

Answer (score 1):

O uso das chaves em ambos os cenários delimitou o escopo da variável. O escopo é o treco de código onde a variável ainda está "viva".

No cenário 1 o escopo em que foi usado o println não definia qualquer variável com o nome "val" e além disso a variável ainda não havia sido inicializada (colocada na memória). Já no cenário 2 o escopo da variável "private int val" é toda a classe e o bloco faz parte dela, logo o java atribuiu 2 e depois 1, após a inicialização a variavél está na memória e portanto pode ser usada pelos metódos.

Comment: Mas não existe declaração no bloco de inicialização de nenhum dos cenários. Existem apenas uma referência e uma atribuição.

Comment: "Illegal forward reference" significa que você está tentando usando uma variável antes de ela ser definida. O erro vem no System.out.println no cenário 1. Quando ao cenário 2, o java procurou uma variável declarada com o nome val e atribuiu 2 depois atribuiu 1. Se vc trocar o bloco de lugar a saída será 2.

Comment: Sim. O que não entendo é pq eu não posso referenciar uma variável "não definida" mas posso atribuir numa variável "não definida".

Comment: Isso aqui pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090669/why-do-we-need-to-declare-the-variable-before-we-use-it-in-some-languages-but-n