# Como faço para chamar um método que está numa outra classe no onclick

Tags: classes, método

Galera estou com uma duvida basicamente simples, porem estou viajando nas ideias.

Tenho um class chamada `chamada`:

```java
@Override
public boolean onLongPressClickListener(View view, int position) {
    // opcional, utilize o valor que achar melhor
    int **tamanhoPadraoCompartilhamento** = 395; 

    String imgPath = DataUrl.getUrlCustom(mList.get(position)
                  .getUrlPhoto(), tamanhoPadraoCompartilhamento);

    Log.i("log", "Path img em Server: " + imgPath);

    picassoDownloadImg(imgPath);

    return true;
}
```

porem estou já em outra `class` eu quero só chamar o método. (`tamanhoPadraoCompartilhamento`) acho que seja isso. Aqui segue a class que estou tentando fazer a invocação do método.

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //campo onde vou chamar o método da outra class

}
```

Bom como eu faço para chamar o método.

---

eu tenho uma class com uma determinada função para compartilhar uma imagem pressionando um banner no aplicativo.

Então, vou colocar essa mesma função em botão em um cardView.

esse código está em uma class com o nome **CarFragment**.

```
/*
    MÉTODO QUE COMPARTILHAR O BANNER.
 */
@Override
public boolean onLongPressClickListener(View view, int position) {


    int tamanhoPadraoCompartilhamento = 395; // opcional, utilize o valor que achar melhor
    String imgPath = DataUrl.getUrlCustom(mList.get(position).getUrlPhoto(), tamanhoPadraoCompartilhamento);
    Log.i("log", "Path img em Server: " + imgPath);

    picassoDownloadImg(imgPath);
    return true;
}

private void picassoDownloadImg(String imgPath) {
    Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(imgPath)
            .into(new Target() {
                      @Override
                      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                          try {
                              String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                              File myDir = new File(root + "/partiuapp");
                              boolean success = true;

                              // CRIANDO DIRETÓRIO CASO NÃO EXISTA
                              if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                  success = myDir.mkdirs();
                              }

                              // CLÁUSULA DE GUARDA
                              if (!success) {
                                  return;
                              }

                              String name = "shared_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                              myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                              FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                              bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                              out.flush();
                              out.close();
                              shareEventImg(name); // CHAMA O CÓDIGO INTENT PARA COMPARTILHAR A IMG
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                      }
                  }
            );
}

private void shareEventImg(String imgName) {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Melhor Aplicativo de Eventos de Maceió");
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/partiuapp";
    File photoFile = new File(imagePath, imgName);

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartilhar imagem"));
}
```

Eu tenho outra Class com  o nome **CarAdapter**

onde eu quero que ela faça a função da primeira class que é compartilhar, porem em um botão.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View  view) {
             Log.i("log", "passou aqui: ");

        }
```

SEGUINDO A LOGICA DA PRIMEIRA CLASS O QUE POSSO FAZER PARA QUE NA CLASSE CarAdapter CHAME O METODO DA PRIMEIRA CLASSE QUE É COMPARTILHA???

obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta está meio vaga, mas para executar métodos de outra classe você tem duas opções:

**Opção 1**

Utilizar um método que está declarado como `static`, como por exemplo:

```
public static double somar(double a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Assim você pode utiliza-lo apenas requisitando-o da classe, como por exemplo se este método estivesse na classe `Calculo`:

```
Calculo.somar(2, 3); // Retorna 5
```

---

**Opção 2** *(Que me parece ser o seu caso)*

Você deve ter uma instância da classe em que está o método, que ficaria algo como o seguinte:

```
tela1.tamanhoPadraoCompartilhamento();
```

Comment: ok Sorack vou validar.

Comment: porque o método tem que ser static?

Comment: Porque quando você cria o método como `static` ele se torna método da classe e não necessita de instância para ser executado

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo da uma olhada nessa pergunta aqui: [Blocos estáticos, herança e construtores em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104512/blocos-est%C3%A1ticos-heran%C3%A7a-e-construtores-em-java). Não é 100% o que você perguntou mas dá pra ter uma idéia