# Como deixar valor padrão em ArrayList estática em Java?

Tags: java, login, arraylist, construtor, métodos-estáticos

Eu estou fazendo um programa com tela de login e tenho uma dúvida:
Quero *settar* uma conta "administrador" num `ArrayList` estático e não sei como proceder (ou se isso seria algo plausível). Não pretendo alterar a conta administrador e portanto pode ser um valor inserido num "construtor". O problema com o qual me deparei é este: O `ArrayList`, por ser estático, é utilizado via chamada de classe, e não de objeto, portanto não há como ter um construtor.

```
package control;

import internal.Login;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginControlador {
    public static String ADMIN_USER = "administrador"; // QUERO EVITAR ISSO
    public static String ADMIN_PASS = "senha"; // E ISSO
    private static List <Login> users = new ArrayList<>(); // QUERO MANTER UM VALOR PADRÃO AQUI DENTRO

    public static void cadastrarUsuario(String username, String password){
        Login novoUsuario = new Login(username, password);
        users.add(novoUsuario);
    }

    public static boolean fazerLogin(String username, String password){
        for (Login user : users){
            if (user.getUsername().equals(username) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é verdade que não tem construtor, tem [uma resposta mostrando o uso de construtor estático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104512/101). Então seria algo assim (não garanto porque não tem detalhes de como deveria ser):

```
static {
    users.add(new Login(ADMIN_USER, ADMIN_PASS);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/StaticConstructor.java).

Este código pode até servir para um exercício, mas se fosse colocado em produção ele teria vários problemas.

Comment: Vou me aprofundar nisso, não sabia sobre esse "construtor". Esse código é apenas para exercício sem cunho profissional, pois estou iniciando estudos na parte de organização de classes e regras para segurança e encapsulamento agora. Obrigado!!